# Is it possible to map a user inside the docker container to an outside user?

Tags: linux, docker

I know that one can use the `--user` option with Docker to run a container as a certain user, but in my case, my Docker image has a user inside it, let us call that user `manager`. Now is it possible to map that user to a user on host? For example, if there is a user `john` on the host, can we map `john` to `manager`?

Comment: https://success.docker.com/article/introduction-to-user-namespaces-in-docker-engine

Comment: The MySQL image supports using the `--user` argument properly as [documented here](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql#running-as-an-arbitrary-user), which is a nice solution when you move from native MySQL to a containerized version.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can set the user from the host, but you should modify your Dockerfile a bit to deal with run time user.

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Override user name at build. If build-arg is not passed, will create user named `default_user`
ARG DOCKER_USER=default_user

# Create a group and user
RUN addgroup -S $DOCKER_USER && adduser -S $DOCKER_USER -G $DOCKER_USER

# Tell docker that all future commands should run as this user
USER $DOCKER_USER
```

Now, build the Docker image:

`docker build --build-arg DOCKER_USER=$(whoami) -t docker_user .`

The new user in Docker will be the Host user.

`docker run --rm docker_user ash -c "whoami"`

Another way is to pass host user ID and group ID without creating the user in Dockerfile.

```
export UID=$(id -u)
export GID=$(id -g)
docker run -it \
    --user $UID:$GID \
    --workdir="/home/$USER" \
    --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
    --volume="/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
    --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
    alpine ash -c "whoami"
```

You can further read more about the user in docker [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002024753/http://gbraad.nl/blog/non-root-user-inside-a-docker-container.html) and [here](https://faun.pub/set-current-host-user-for-docker-container-4e521cef9ffc).

Comment: I know about the 2nd option already. About your 1st method, would it work if I build the image on a different machine than where I am using it?

Comment: yes it should work if the build command is the one that i suggested

Comment: The first option does not deal with the UID which is the thing that actually matters.  To map to the host user, the UID in the container must match the UID of the host user but the usernames need not match.  So the issue is ensuring that UID exists inside the container. The second example does by mounting those /etc files but the first does nothing. It might work but if so, it's only by coincidence.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is through an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

### Example

This example relies on [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu/) which is present in recent [Debian derivatives](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gosu&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=main), not yet in Alpine 3.13 (but [is in edge](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=gosu)).

You could run this image as follow:

```sh
docker run --rm -it \
  --env UID=$(id -u) \
  --env GID=$(id -g) \
  -v "$(pwd):$(pwd)" -w "$(pwd)" \
  imagename
```

```
tree
.                          
├── Dockerfile
└── files/
    └── entrypoint
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ...

# [...]

ARG DOCKER_USER=default_user

RUN addgroup "$DOCKER_USER" \
 && adduser "$DOCKER_USER" -G "$DOCKER_USER"

RUN wget -O- https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.12/gosu-amd64 |\
    install /dev/stdin /usr/local/bin/gosu

COPY files /

RUN chmod 0755 /entrypoint \
 && sed "s/\$DOCKER_USER/$DOCKER_USER/g" -i /entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

#### files/entrypoint

```sh
#!/bin/sh
  
set -e
set -u

: "${UID:=0}"
: "${GID:=${UID}}"

if [ "$#" = 0 ]
then set -- "$(command -v bash 2>/dev/null || command -v sh)" -l
fi

if [ "$UID" != 0 ]
then
        usermod -u "$UID" "$DOCKER_USER" 2>/dev/null && {
                groupmod -g "$GID" "$DOCKER_USER" 2>/dev/null ||
                usermod -a -G "$GID" "$DOCKER_USER"
        }
        set -- gosu "${UID}:${GID}" "${@}"
fi

exec "$@"
```

### Notes

- `UID` is normally a [read-only variable in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-UID), but it will work as expected if set by the docker `--env` flag
- I choose `gosu` for it's simplicity, but you *could* make it work with [`su`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) or `sudo`; it will need more configuration however
- if you don't want to specify two `--env` switch, you could do something like: `--env user="$(id -u):$(id -g)"` and in the `entrypoint`: `uid=${user%:*} gid=${user#*:}`; note at this point the `UID` variable will be read-only in bash that's why I switched to lower-case... rest of the adaptation is left to the reader

Comment: I tried this on an OSX host but got the following error `error: failed switching to "501:20": operation not permitted`.

Comment: @tomsgd : this is likely caused by the fact you are trying to launch your entry point as a non-root user... note how the example here does not set a user so things get executed as root...

Answer (score -2):

There is no simple solution that handles all use cases. Solving these problems is continuous work, a part of life in the containerized world.

There is no magical parameter that you could add to a `docker exec` or `docker run` invocation and reliably cause the containerized software to no longer run into permissions issues during operations on host-mapped volumes. Unless your mapped directories are chmod-0777-and-come-what-may (DON'T), you **will** be running into permissions issues and you **will** be solving them as you go, and this is the task you should try becoming efficient at, instead of trying to find a miracle once-and-forever solution that will never exist.